# implementation of routing in my app

Tags: routes, shortest-path

I need to implement shortest distance between two points in the map in my app. Can I integrate Google maps to do it for me or do I have to use other sources like openstreetmaps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try the direction service from Google maps API. Try this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService)

In case if you don't want to use Google. Then try out [Haversine formula](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe). But you will need to have the coordinates for it.

Comment: Haversine formula only gives me distance between two points. All I have is gps co-ordinates and I need to consider traffic too in calculating the shortest path.

Comment: In case you need traffic then it will be better to go with Google API